# Snakemake wants to run job although output file already exists

Tags: python, offline, snakemake

I have a workflow that begins by downloading files from a public database, and then in subsequent steps processes these files to create several aggregated data tables.

I’m testing the workflow on a machine with no internet connection. I ran the preliminary data download steps on another machine and copied them over to this machine, and now I’m trying to run the rest of the workflow. When I run `snakemake -np` it reports that all of the data download jobs still need to be completed, even though the target files already exist. I’ve even marked these files as `ancient()` in the subsequent processing rules, but this doesn’t help.

How can I convince Snakemake that these jobs don’t need to be re-run?

Comment: Try flag `--reason` ([`Print the reason for each executed rule.`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#OUTPUT)) to figure out why snakemake wants to run it.

Comment: Brilliant. Dependent file with newer timestamp. `touch`ing the downloaded files solved the issue! @JeeYeem, if you post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to give you credit!

Comment: Thinking again, `ancient()` should have solved your problem, right? Any clue why not?

Comment: @JeeYem I may have erroneously marked the target files as `ancient()`, rather than the file they depended on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag `--reason` [prints the reason for each executed rule](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#OUTPUT).