# How can I execute a single Snakemake rule without triggering input rules?

Tags: snakemake

In a Snakemake workflow, I would like to run a rule without it triggering any of the rules that produce its input.

A sample scenario is as follows: I have a rule A that is costly and produces many output files from input files:

```
rule A:
  input: "{name}.in"
  output: "{name}.out"
  shell: "touch {input} {output}" #just a dummy, replace with actual costly task
```

A second rule B takes the output files and uploads them to a server:

```
rule B:
  input: "{name}.out"
  output: touch("{name}.up")
  shell: "curl -F 'data={input}' http://google.com/upload
```

The third rule C is just a usual `all` rule that acts as the terminal rule to trigger all input ones:

```
names = ["x1","x2","x3"] # dummy for long list
rule C:
  input: expand("{name}.up",name=names)
```

Assume there was an error in `rule B` such that the expensive `rule A` completed, but `rule B` has not.

I would like to trigger `rule B` and `rule C` only, in such a way that `rule A` is not.

The problem is that for some reason, rule A will always run, despite many `x1.out` being present. This shouldn't be the case but it is.

I'm now looking for a Snakemake CLI option that allows me to prevent `rule A` from being run.

I could find a CLI option `--until` which does exactly the opposite, it runs all rules up to a certain rule. I would like to be able to do the opposite, something like `--from` which starts at `B` and fails if inputs cannot be found.

I don't know exactly why `rule A` gets triggered. The input files have not been updated. Nonetheless A is run (in fact it's much more complicated, the above is simplified a lot).

In short: is there a CLI option that allows me to specify a rule that should be run, including all downstream rules, but none of the upstream rules? Or is this impossible?

Comment: I would try to find out why rule A is triggered since that seems to be the actual problem. For experimenting, you could use the `touch` command to make the input of rule B older than its output. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56807933/1114453

Comment: @dariober I did try to find out what happened but couldn't figure it out and was hoping there was another way. It could be due to a rule being there that has no input? I touched all of the intermediary output, but it was still not enough.

Comment: [`--reason` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426853/3998252) would be helpful to figure out why.

Comment: `touch {input} {output}` updates the time of input. That may be the cause.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy I tried, it was that some input changed, can't investigate anymore since the problem was solved in another way.
DmitryKuzminov: I abstracted a lot of the details away, the actual workflow is a lot more complicated.

Comment: try the `-r` option which prints the reasons why rules are being rerun ! (in combination with the `-n` to make a dry run of course !)