# snakemake repeating rules whose output files already exist

Tags: workflow, snakemake

I am running snakemake (v7.6.2) and I noticed that, unlike its 'principles', it is attempting to re-run steps of a pipeline whose output files already exist.

In my first run I had the following DAG:

[image]

which finished successfully, but I now want to add another rule to it (`quast_first`), as shown in the following 'updated' DAG:

[image]

(I have done that by adding the output of `quast_first` as input for `quast_second`)

If I call a dry run, I'd be expecting the following rules to be re-executed:

1. `quast_first`: output does not exist, it was not part of the previous workflow
2. `quast_second`: although the output exists, it has a new dependency (`quast_first`), although, for this specific case, the output should be the exact same, as the output of `quast_first` is just a dependency (so no input) for `quast_second`

However, I see that snakemake wants to re-generate the whole workflow. Below is an extract from calling a dry run with the `--reason` flag, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411496/snakemake-wants-to-run-job-although-output-file-already-exists):

```
rule symLinkFQ:
    input: logs/BORD1725, /nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04
    output: symLinkFq/BORD1725
    log: /home/ngs/tempSnakemake/20220420Microbiology_q20/logs/BORD1725
    jobid: 34
    reason: Updated input files: /nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04
    wildcards: barcode=BORD1725
    resources: mem_mb=1000, disk_mb=1000, tmpdir=/tmp

ln -s /nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04 symLinkFq/BORD1725
```

However, I can confirm that the output of the rule `symLinkFQ` does exist (workdir is `/home/ngs/tempSnakemake/20220420Microbiology_q20`),

```
[ngs@vngs20x ~/tempSnakemake/20220420Microbiology_q20]$ ll symLinkFq/BORD1725
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ngs ngs 125 24. Mai 14:01 symLinkFq/BORD1725 -> /nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04
```

so I don't quite understand what is meant by:

```
reason: Updated input files: /nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04`, as shown above:
```

also at the end of the dry run it shows again that the whole workflow will be executed if I call it:

```
Job stats:
job               count    min threads    max threads
--------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                   1              1              1
cat_fastq             4              1              1
flye                  4              1              1
minimap_first         4              1              1
minimap_second        4              1              1
quast_first           4              1              1
quast_second          4              1              1
racon_first           4              1              1
racon_second          4              1              1
symLinkFQ             4              1              1
total                37              1              1
```

I have been using previous versions of Snakemake (v.5.* mainly) and as far as I recall this is the first time that I encounter this issue (Snakemake re-running rules whose output files already exist). Can it be that this is version-related, that I now, for example, have to pass a command line argument to snakemake telling it not to re-generate output files that already exist (although I would always expect this to be the default behaviour)?

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way - were there in fact any changes to `/nexus/Gridion/20220420Microbiology_q20/no_sample/20220405_1846_X1_FAT23098_47b43b4a/High_accuracy_basecalling/pass/barcode04`? That looks like it's a directory if I know my Nanopore outputs. (Is your sequencing/basecalling completely done?)
You might try defining the path to the directory in `params` instead of `input` if you're sure it's going to be there/can handle it not being there if e.g. a barcode drops out completely and don't care about updated files within the dir.

Comment: no file was updated in any of those directories, and basecalling is long finished (sometime in April), so nothing is being written in those folders

Comment: This could be a version issue, I might be wrong, but at some point (maybe six months ago) there was a bug in identifying rules to re-run.

Answer (score 1):

turns out that this is indeed version related. I removed snakemake `v7.6.2` and isntalled `v5.8.1` and snakemake no longer wants to repeat rules whose output files exist. Same bug is present at v`7.8.0`, which is the latest release version

Comment: Thanks for opening [an issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1677) about it.

Comment: Note that in reply to the filing of an issue, mbhall88 has posted [a workaround](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1677#issuecomment-1138019777) along with a justification.